# std::pair is calling the default constructor for one of its members

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, stl, std-pair

So I have this code line:

```
statesArray.push_back(std::pair<States, StateSettings>(States::funMode, StateSettings(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)));
```

`statesArray` is an object of type `QVector<std::pair<States, StateSettings> >`.

`StateSettings` class have this two constructors (from witch the default one is deleted):

```
StateSettings() = delete;
StateSettings(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e = 0, int f = 0);
```

When compiling, I get this error:

```
Error   2   error C2280: 'StateSettings::StateSettings(void)' : attempting to reference a deleted function.
```

Why `std::pair` is trying to call the deleted default constructor, if I pass it an object explicitly-constructed with one non-default constructor?

How ho I solve this?

Comment: From the Qt's reference: *"The values stored in the various containers can be of any assignable data type. To qualify, a type must provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator."*

Comment: [This may be fixed in C++17.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yep, that was the problem. Switched to `std::vector` and everything works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Try implementing a copy constructor

Comment: Try using std::make_pair, it forwards the arguments to the correct ctor:

struct foo
{
    int _i;
    foo() = delete; //not really needed
    foo(int i)
        : _i(i)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto my_pair = std::make_pair<foo, bool>(4, true);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << my_pair.first._i << "!\n";
}

Comment: @Jonathan Ah! An impostor has my name! LOL Anyway, the problem is the container's instantiation. You can't have a container which holds items which are not default constructable. The error does not come from constructing the objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [commented by Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520188/stdpair-is-calling-the-default-constructor-for-one-of-its-members#comment54821829_33520188), the [Qt Standard specifies](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-container-classes) that the value type stored in `QVector`, and any other Qt Generic container, must:

> Be of any assignable data type. To qualify, a type must provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator.

The value type specified in the question clearly does not meet these qualifications.

One possible way of getting around this would be to store pointers to the values:

```
QVector<std::pair<States, StateSettings>*> statesArray;
```